# Running Python Process Overnight and Working Around System Reboots?

Tags: python, process, system, reboot

I am using a KDB function to run a python script remotely from a Windows task machine. There will be times when this script will be running in the background overnight and during the weekend. The issue is that there could be unexpected system reboots that cut off a KDB Connection and/or delete the Python process. What are some viable workarounds for this issue? Ideally the Python process should be robust enough so that if it errors out, it will start back up again.

Will Python's retry library be useful in this situation?

https://pypi.org/project/retrying/

Comment: You could use retry but just a while true try except could be a dirty workaround. Then just use systemctl to get it to restart after reboot.

Comment: Is systemctl compatible with Windows? What does this do exactly?

Comment: Oops, I’m thinking Linux again, apologies, a relevant equivalent would be [startup](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000322.htm)